# How can I save/restore window layouts in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I somehow save window layout (with opened files) in VS Code and then restore it?

I am looking for an alternative for **Emacs** `C-x r w <register>` where I can interactively open different saved views.

**Example**: split the window into 3 views, open the same file in all of them scroll to different locations, save it, open other view where it's only 1 window open and then restore the 3 window view(the one I saved).

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for: workspaces in visual studio code automatically save the layout for that workspace. It would be ideal if you could save multiple layouts for the same workspace, and be able to switch between them. I don't know how to do that; I came across your unanswered question when looking for the same thing.

Comment: I've found that even if I setup the window how I want it , then save the workspace, close it, then open it, it doesn't keep the window how I set it up. It chooses another size and another location, so it seems that this is broken in Visual Studio Code 1.48.0.

Answer (score 3):

As for builtin VS Code features at the time of this writing for window layout, the best you can get is along the lines of the following commands in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) (a couple of "hardcoded" presets):

- `View: Two Rows Editor Layout`
- `View: Two Rows Right Editor Layout`
- `View: Three Rows Editor Layout`
- `View: Single Column Editor Layout`
- `View: Toggle Centered Layout`
- `View: Two Columns Editor Layout`
- `View: Two Columns Bottom Editor Layout`
- `View: Three Columns Editor Layout`
- `View: Grid Editor Layout (2x2)`

You can also change the keybindings for those things using the following command IDs:

```
workbench.action.editorLayoutSingle
workbench.action.editorLayoutThreeColumns
workbench.action.editorLayoutThreeRows
workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoByTwoGrid
workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoColumns
workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoColumnsBottom
workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoRows
workbench.action.editorLayoutTwoRowsRight
```

There have been several requests in the past to get a layout store/recall feature added to VS Code, which are all now closed (I don't think this is an exhaustive list):

- [Allow to save window layouts #66883](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138263)
- [Ability to persist, restore, switch between and sync multiple VSCode layouts (panels, views, sidebars, editor groups, etc) #138263](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138263)
- [Support saving layouts and setting a default #148488](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148488)

---

As for non-builtin solutions for window layout, you could look for extensions provided related features. I've seen several people mention [`ctf0.save-editors-layout`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.save-editors-layout) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>. I haven't tried it for myself so I'm not necessarily vouching for it- just mentioning it.

---

As for saving and restoring open editors, see [VSCode: Store and reopen a group of file tabs so that I reset a specific environment in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62808043/11107541).

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio Code: File -> Preferences -> Settings.
Search for Window Restore Windows -> click the dropdown and select "preserve". This will save Visual Studio Code's window layout for the next time you reopen the program.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

- File/Preferences/Params
- At right top corner click on "show params as JSON"
- Add this param : window.restoreWindows": "all"

This param allow to restaure all opened file by project/folder.
If you open 2 windows with 2 differents projects, each will have files restored :)

Warning : visual studio code doesn't manage more than one windows in same on launch.
To fix that you need to create a file.bat containing this code :

```
code C:\path\of\one\folder && code C:\path\of\another\folder (for example)
```

and then create a shortcut somewhere to call this file.bat with lauchy for example :)

Answer (score 1):

Open the Command Palette

```
View -> Command Palette...
```

or press

```
CTRL+SHIFT+P
```

then search for `layout` and make visible/invisible the panel as your needs

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this vscode extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.save-editors-layout