# Are there any VS Code extensions that name and change the color of grouped tabs like Chrome?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

Chrome has an amazing tab grouping feature that I would like to see in VS Code. Essentially, in Chrome you are able to add a new group, name it, and choose a color to highlight all the tabs in the group.

[image]

The only things I have seen on this are Tab Groups [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66257977/12846242), and custom themes [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67845465/12846242). Is there an extension that combines the two ideas into something that mimics google's tab orginization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easily achievable with VSCode extensions, due to the way the API works.

What you can get though, is tab grouping in the Explorer view with something like this [Favorites](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kdcro101.favorites) extension.